# splitting a strings inside a list

Tags: python, string, split

I have a list in python:

```
hand_of_cards = ["4H", "6D", "7D", "7C", "3C"]

for char in hand_of_cards:
    if hand_of_cards[1] == "S" and hand_of_cards[1] == "C":
        black_counter += 1
```

I know if I want split a list of strings I can use split:

```
hand_of_cards.split(",")
```

But its already in the form that I need it in and I would like to evaluate the string value not the int attached to it. So essentially:

```
["4H"] to ["4","H"]
```

Comment: So, what __exactly__ do you want for your complete output?

Comment: How would face cards be represented in your list?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is one way:

```
x = "4H"

[x[:-1], x[-1]]  # ['4', 'H']
```

Apply it to a list via a list comprehension:

```
[[x[:-1], x[-1]] for x in lst]

# [['4', 'H'], ['6', 'D'], ['7', 'D'], ['7', 'C'], ['3', 'C']]
```

Comment: adjusted the for loop index, but its still not splitting the characters i.e if hand_of_cards[:-1] == "S" and hand_of_cards[-1] == "C":

Answer (score 1):

You can use `map` with regex:

```
import re
hand_of_cards = ["4H", "6D", "7D", "7C", "3C", "JH"]
new_cards = list(map(lambda x:re.findall('\d+|[A-Z]+', x), hand_of_cards))
```

Output:

```
[['4', 'H'], ['6', 'D'], ['7', 'D'], ['7', 'C'], ['3', 'C'], ['JH']]
```

Comment: @chrisz, i think it's fair to assume a [Standard 52-card deck](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_52-card_deck) unless otherwise stated.

Comment: @chrisz While the OP did not specify what his desired output would be for face cards, It may be reasonable to assume that the output could be the string value encapsulated in a list.

Comment: @chrisz I'm looking for occurrences of a certain character so I can increment a counter, so if "C" or "S" is true, the black counter increments by one up to three. Face cards are displayed as "KD" or ten is "TH", but I only need the color value.

Comment: @Ajax1234 with this clarification I still think there is an issue with not splitting face cards, but with the clarification about how tens are represented, your initial answer now works, using just `list()`

Comment: @SeabassGoslin can you clarify what your desired output would for `["4H", "6D", "7D", "7C", "3C", "JH"]`?

Comment: @Ajax1234 Absolutely, the red_counter would increment if the list contains "H","D" for red cards similarly black_counter for "C", "S". I need 3 blacks and 2 reds, but I just need to know how to split the initial object without a generic separator like "." or ","

Answer (score 0):

Try this code !

```
hand_of_cards = ["4H", "6D", "7D", "7C", "3C"]

for i in range(0,len(hand_of_cards)):
    l=list(hand_of_cards[i])
    hand_of_cards.remove(hand_of_cards[i])
    hand_of_cards.insert(i,l)

print(hand_of_cards)
```

**Output :**

[['4', 'H'], ['6', 'D'], ['7', 'D'], ['7', 'C'], ['3', 'C']]

Comment: I'm able to split it, however I'm not sure how make it iterate across the 1st index of every sublist, my program will evaluate the first index then make an entirely new deck without evaluating the rest of the sublists in the new list.